# How to aggregate this simple SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery, window-functions

I have a table like this:

```
ID Value Key
0  ValA  0
1  ValB  0
2  ValC  1
4  ValD  0
5  ValE  1
```

Apart from the table itself, I am also interested in the first ID with Key==1. I could use the following query to find it:

```
SELECT Key FROM MyTable WHERE Key=1 ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1
```

Now, I'd like to combine the query to a regular SELECT, so that I have all the aggregated information in one go.

My following attempt failed, I tried:

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    Value,
    Key,
    (SELECT Key FROM MyTable WHERE Key=1 ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1 AS FirstKeyIs1) 
FROM MyTable
```

How should I rewrite my query? The expected behaviour would have `FirstKeyIs1` be 2. The goal is eventually filter out the IDs with a key property before `2`.

```
ID Value Key FirstKeyIs1
0  ValA  0   2
1  ValB  0   2
2  ValC  1   2
4  ValD  0   2
5  ValE  1   2
```

Comment: I'm using MySQL.

Comment: Key is a reserved word in MySQL. Maybe start over.

Answer (score 2):

If your database supports window functions, you can do:

```
select
    t.*,
    min(case when key = 1 then id end) over() firstKeyIs1
from mytable t
```

Otherwise, your approach using a subquery is OK. You just need to move the column alias out of the subquery - and presumably, you want to return the `id` rather than the `key`:

```
select
    t.*,
    (select id from mytable where key = 1 order by id limit 1) firstKeyIs1 
from mytable
```

Or you can use aggregation in the subquery:

```
select
    t.*,
    (select min(id) from mytable where key = 1) firstKeyIs1 
from mytable
```

Comment: @HelloWorld: window functions were added in MySQL 8.0, so the first query will work only in MySQL 8.0. The two other queries work on all versions of MySQL.